# Ensure column values match between tables when one matches another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table that references another table and I want to be sure that other columns - outside of the reference key - match for rows that are referenced. My data model currently looks something like this:

```
           groups
-----------------------------
  Column  | Type | Modifiers
----------+------+-----------
 name     | text | not null

PRIMARY KEY: name


               A
--------------------------------
  Column   |  Type  | Modifiers
-----------+--------+-----------
 id        | bigint | not null
 some_data | text   | not null
 b         | bigint |
 group     | text   | not null

PRIMARY KEY: id
FOREIGN KEYS:
        group REFERENCES groups(name)
        b REFERENCES B(id)


               B
--------------------------------
  Column   |  Type  | Modifiers 
-----------+--------+-----------
 id        | bigint | not null
 value     | text   | not null
 group     | text   | not null

PRIMARY KEY: id
FOREIGN KEYS:
        group REFERENCES groups(name)
```

So the issue here is that I want to make sure that any row in B referenced by a row in A is in the same "group" as the A row. I've heard the right way to do this is to just add the extra column to the foreign key. Problem is, when I try to change the foreign key to `(b, group) REFERENCES B(id, group)` I get

```
there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "B"
```

which is technically true, although because `id` is unique the combination of `id` with any other column is trivially unique also.

I could add the `group` column to the primary key, but that seems redundant since `id` is already unique and totally sufficient to identify a row. I could add a uniqueness constraint or a unique index, but that also seems like asking PostgreSQL to do more work than it has to do.

I should note that rows in B have meaning beyond the context of being referenced by a row in A.

Is there any way to ensure this constraint, or do I have to just bite the bullet and make PostgreSQL do extra work to enforce redundant uniqueness?

Comment: Sounds like a triggered constraint on your A table, because that's where your optional link to table B sits.   Your data model defines a relation between A and Groups and another between B and Groups, but not one between A and B.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a trigger just because I don't trust myself to write it properly - but if that's less work for PostgreSQL than maintaining useless uniqueness (in terms of storage space if nothing else), then I'd be happy to accept it as an answer. Assuming, of course, that there's no way to do it without triggers *or* rendundant uniqueness.

Comment: You *want to be sure that other columns - outside of the reference key - match*. This seems to say the modifiers in Tables A and B those in match those in `groups`. If so there is a simple way of doing that. Remove the modifiers (drop the column) from Table A and Table B. When needed just join to `group` through the PK:FK already defined. No additional constraints, index are required.  If they only exist in one place they will always be the same and you will not have any maintenance issues.

Comment: How would I do the JOIN with `groups` if I drop the `group` column that allows me to associate them with a group? Or did you mean just drop the column `b` on the A table? In that case, how could I tell which B - if any - belongs to any given A? I could still associate them with the group to which they each belong, but that would destroy the association between the two tables.

Comment: You do not drop the `groups` column. You drop the `modifiers` column from both tables, then get the modifiers through joining by 'group'.  If you need to see the modifiers at any time you can create a view.

Comment: None of these tables have a column named `Modifiers`. Those are displays of table information in a format similar to what you'd get with a `\d` command.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `group` to the primary key.  You can add a separate unique constraint/index:

```
create unique index unq_a_group_id on a(group, id);
```

The foreign key can reference a unique index.  In general, you want foreign keys that reference primary keys.  However, maintaining this consistency is an exception.

Comment: If the unique index is on `a(group, id)` doesn't that merely restrict multiple rows in A from having the same group and id? That's already enforced by no two rows in A being allowed to share an ID, and I don't think it enforces that rows in B that are referenced by A share the same group.

Comment: @ocket8888 . . . The purpose of the unique index is to support a composite foreign key constraint.

Comment: I don't see how it could do that as an index on A - if it were an index on B and I also committed to that foreign key constraint on A that would make sense.

Comment: @ocket8888 . . . I though the answer was clear that the purpose of the unique index is to support a foreign key declaration.

Comment: There is no foreign key that references A(group, id) in my schema